# How do I display an integer from an NSArray on a UILabel?

Tags: nsstring, integer, nsarray, uilabel, nsinteger

I realize this is a dumb beginner question, but I have been stuck for at least an hour on trying to get an integer value from my array to display on a label when I press a button. The problem is that the label keeps displaying "(null)" no matter what index I put the label to look at. I have tried taking out the quotation marks on the NSArray objects too. It doesn't matter too much whether the objects within the NSArray are integers or strings, but I would at least like to know the syntax on how to put them into the array because I believe that's my problem. If not, show me otherwise please.

My code:
 (.h file)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *redOneTeams;
```

(.m file)

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _redOneTeams = @[
                   @"4351",
                   @"4298",
                   ];
        }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender {
    _teamNumber.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", [_redOneTeams objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Comment: How is this view controller being created? Break this problem into two parts by just saying `_teamNumber.text = @"works!"` in your `saveBtn:`. Then we know if the issue is the array or your outlet to the label.

Comment: I have like 30 other labels in my app that work when displaying NSIntegers,  I'm just trying to get this specific one to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities with your issue.

1. Just set a break point on `initWithNibName` and check if this method is triggering . I feel like this method
   is not getting called somehow. So you array is not getting set.
2. If you are able not find out why `initWithNibName` is not getting called then you can shift your code into `viewDidLoad` method.

Just try out these things probably you will catch issue.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of options here:

1- Put the numbers directly into your array as numbers:

```
_redOneTeams = @[
               @4351,
               @4298,
               ];
```

This is automatically recognized as literals/numbers. If you do this, then you can just call it with:

```
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender 
{
  _teamNumber.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", [_redOneTeams objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

2- Another more convoluted way but to show you how you can unwrap numbers from NSStrings:

Keep your array declared with NSString elements and then get the value form the NSString as follows:

```
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender 
{
  _teamNumber.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", [[_redOneTeams objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah,  I see. Xcode autocorrected to put @"%@" for my text. Thanks! I'll check on it tomorrow to see if it worked.

Comment: It turns out my array was never even being initialized even though I had it in the custom initialization in the code that apple supplies when creating a new page... Weird. I ended up initializing the array in my button press method and it worked there. Thanks for the help though!